# Jquery horizontal pan with 100% width element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this 100% witdh container with lots of images in it. I would like to pan it horizontally when I mouseover the parent container.

I've come quite far but I have a few problems.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rH76r/1/)

1. First I have to set the margin left to be percentage based, else it wont show all the images. To do this, I have to get the full width of the inner container, but I'm unable to do this.

   ```
   $('.merken').mousemove(function (event) {
           var left = event.pageX;

           $('.slider').css({
               'margin-left': '-' + left + 'px'
           });


       });
   ```
2. The thumb-container now has a fixed width, but i need to make this an auto width. Right now this makes sure that the images in the container dont show one-by-one. How do I fix this?

   ```
   .thumb-container { width:2000px;}
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want to do. But I think that you should use the .width() jquery method:

```
       $('.merken').mousemove(function(event){

            var left = event.pageX;
            var percentleft = left/$('.merken').width();
            var sliderleft = $('.slider').width()*percentleft;

            $('.slider').css({
                'margin-left': '-'+sliderleft+'px'
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rH76r/3/)

```
$('.merken').mousemove(function(event){
        var left = (event.pageX*100)/$('.thumb-container').width();
        $('.slider').css({
            'margin-left': '-'+left+'%'
        });             
});
```

and

```
.thumb-container{
        width:200%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those intrested, fixed it like this:

```
var conb = $('.slider').width();

        $('.merken').mousemove(function(event){

            var left = (event.pageX*100)/conb;

            $('.slider').css({
                'margin-left': '-'+left+'%'
            });

        });
```